# What's correct way to make natural number rule in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I guess I have some bigger problem in understanding prolog, but since I can't quite formulate it, I focus on single problem

I want to create a rule `natural(X)` that is true if `X` is 1,2,3,4,...
More importantly, I want both: `natural(5)` to be true **and** `natural(X)` to output `X=1; X=2; ...`

---

So, I explain rule as follows (pseudologic):

```
natural(1) must be true
natural(X) is true if natural(X-1) is true
```

or, in terms of prolog:

```
natural(1).
natural(X) :- natural(X-1).
```

but I get a problem - if I try `natural(5)` I get infinite recursion
debugger says that program evaluates:

```
natural(5)
 natural(5-1)
  natural(5-1-1)
   natural(5-1-1-1)
    natural(5-1-1-1-1)
     natural(5-1-1-1-1-1)
      natural(5-1-1-1-1-1-1)
...
```

---

I guess the problem is in `X-1` not being evaluated?
Let's try to fix that:

```
natural(1).
natural(X) :-
  Y is X-1,
  natural(Y).
```

now, `natural(5)` works as expected
but, if I use `natural(X)` I get `X=1; Exception: Arguments not sufficiently instantiated (Y is X-1)`

---

ok, I guess the problem is we try to evaluate stuff that can be without value yet
If I try to use `Y = X-1` we return to first problem. `Y == X-1` returns `false`

The only solution that I found to work was switching lines and definition order:

```
natural(1).
natural(X) :-
  natural(Y),
  X is Y+1.
```

Changing last line to `=` gives "+1+1+1..." results. `==` just fails.

This solution works great in generating `X=1; X=2; ...`, but when I use it as check (`natural(5)`), it goes in "0,(0,1),(0,1,2),(0,1,2,3),..." order. Yes I get correct result, but the path there is long and not what I would've imagined.
I would've stopped here, if I haven't seen the faster way of checking for natural(5) in previous solution.

---

So, **what is better way of creating this rule have I missed?**

I guess one way would be separating "true/false" queries from generator queries... But is there a way to make it "evaluate if possible to evaluate", i.e. separate only-constants from has-variables? `var(X-1)` is false somehow...

Comment: Use [tag:successor-arithmetics] first to define natural numbers. In it, it is all natural, with `(is)/2` it is very hard and incomplete. Then, use `library(clpfd)`, which is even more natural. Think of: `X #>= 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dealing with naturals is usually improved considerably by using `succ/2`. `is/2`, as you have discovered, is *required* for Prolog to evaluate an arithmetic expression, but it has a single instantiation pattern: `-Number is +Expr`. Without constraints, it would be total insanity for that to have a completely open pattern such as `?Number is ?Expr`.

`succ/2`, on the other hand, has two patterns: `succ(+Pred, -Succ)` and `succ(-Pred, +Succ)`. To wit: `succ(X, 3)` unifies X = 2 and `succ(2, X)` unifies X = 3. Although `succ(X, Y)` still is an error. However, you can build a solution to `natural/1` using `succ/2`, with a caveat:

```
natural(1).
natural(X) :- natural(X0), succ(X0, X).
```

Logically, this should be the same as `succ(X0, X), natural(X0)`, but Prolog is not logic, it has an evaluation order. This trick basically forces your request for whether X is a natural to start at X-1, go immediately to X-2, and thence downward until it hits 1, whereupon it can back up and start succeeding. If you supply a negative number, it fails right away because `succ/2` fails for negatives. This works in both of your required ways, but has a nasty problem:

```
?- natural(X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
....

?- natural(5).
true ;
^CAction (h for help) ? abort
```

Yes, we get an infinite loop if we ask for a second result after supplying the value. Prolog goes off trying to find out if 5 ever appears again *after* 5.

A simple solution that avoids the problem is to use `between/3`:

```
natural(X) :- between(1, inf, X).

?- natural(X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
...

?- natural(5).
true.
```

No loop. This would be my preferred solution.

In addition to `var/1` and `nonvar/1` there is also `ground/1`, which can distinguish between terms that have variables and terms that do not. You can use that to make a distinction between (on one side) 5, 3-1, etc. and X, X-1, on the other. In my experience, breaking apart cases like this usually leads to tears and trouble with backwards correctness, but in extreme cases it may be warranted.

At this point you may be feeling a little sour about Prolog's logic. The standard system's arithmetic is on the disappointing side. But clpfd is much more powerful and flexible, and many people recommend you learn that first because it is better at generating solutions (`is/2` really can't generate, but labeling can with clpfd). In my experience, `succ/2` is close enough to Peano arithmetic that integer messing around is often OK, but for anything serious you will want to use clpfd.

Comment: what does `-`, `+` and `?` mean in `-Number is +Expr` and `?Number is ?Expr` ?

Comment: Love your prose. Thanks

Comment: @NooneAtAll These markers tell you whether the parameter is required to be supplied (also known as an input parameter)--this is `+`--or whether the predicate will bind the variable as an output parameter--this is `-`. The `?` indicates that the predicate works whether or not the parameter is instantiated. The `?` instantiation pattern is common for predicates like this, where the predicate can generate or check the parameter.

Comment: @CapelliC thank you! I owe 85% of what I know about Prolog to you!

Comment: "Dealing with naturals is usually improved considerably by using..." `library(`[tag:clpfd]`)`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if number is natural this way:

```
nat(0).
nat(s(X)) :-
    nat(X).
```